# Use ffmpeg to generate video thumbnail without any distortion

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails, video-processing

To get a `200x100` thumbnail from a video, I do `ffmpeg -ss 100 -i /tmp/video.mp4 -frames:v 1 -s 200x100 image.jpg`. But if the source video isn't in the same aspect ratio as `200x100`, the thumbnail gets distorted (either stretched or squished, horizontally or vertically) and it looks bad.

Is there a way that `ffmpeg` can figure out for example that a `500x200` video is `100px` too wide, and remove `50px` from the right and `50px` from the left, making the video `400x200`? And because `400x200` is the same aspect ratio as `200x100`, the thumbnail would have no distortion.

I know there are other tools that can do this to the thumbnails generated by `ffmpeg`, but I'd prefer doing it within `ffmpeg` and not having to process the thumbnails again.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218363/maintaining-ffmpeg-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `force_original_aspect_ratio` option in the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter.

```
ffmpeg -ss 100 -i /tmp/video.mp4 -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 -vf "scale=200:100:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=200:100" image.jpg
```

Comment: Would this work the same when the video is either taller or wider than the aspect ratio of the thumbnail you want? And if for example the video is 100px too wide for the aspect ratio, it would remove equal parts from the left and right (so 50px each)?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - the scaler preserves the SAR in the output, which is not obeyed by third-party apps. Photoshop, e.g. honors the SAR for JPGs but not PNGs. Firefox honors it for neither format.

Comment: @user779159 It will crop the extra if it is too wide or too tall. The cropping will automatically be centered. See the [crop filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) if you want to adjust cropping coordinates.

Comment: If the video is non-square, setsar=1 will produce wrong result. The scaling itself has to produce a raster which is non-distorted when treated as  square-pixel.

Comment: @Mulvya Ah, yes, I overlooked that.

Comment: @Mulvya, I'm confused by your last 2 comments to this answer as I'm a layman when it comes to this stuff. So do I need to add/remove something to LordNeckbeard's answer?

Comment: LN's answer won't work if you are working with videos that have non-square pixels i.e. PAL, NTSC, HDV or anamorphic DVD files. For square pixel videos, like mobile camera videos or most web videos, you'll be fine. My command will work with all sources,

Comment: @Mulvya Are `mp4` files always with square pixels, or does it depend on the specific mp4 file?

Comment: Depends on specific file. Any codec in most formats can have non-square pixels.

Comment: Is there some output from `ffprobe` or something I can use to see if a video has square pixels or not?

Comment: Yes. `ffprobe -show_entries stream=sample_aspect_ratio video.mp4`

Answer (score 4):

If your thumbnail size is 200x100 fixed, then run

```
ffmpeg -ss 100 -i /tmp/video.mp4 -vf "scale='if(gt(dar,200/100),100*dar,200)':'if(gt(dar,200/100),100,200/dar)',setsar=1,crop=200:100"  -frames:v 1 image.jpg
```

The scale filter checks the aspect ratio of the source and scale so that one dimension fits the 200x100 canvas and the other overshoots, unless it's a perfect match. Then the crop filter crops it to 200x100 from the center thus taking care of the out of bounds region.

Comment: This can result in an output less than one of the requested dimensions and will cause crop to fail (using an input with a 115:87 SAR for example).

Comment: Yeah, the `-1` doesn't account for SAR. Corrected.