# Getting pure html content from web page

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm trying to retrieve wysiwyg html content from a web page (generated with apache wicket, but I don't think it cares).
I tried the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage) but I always get an HTML body like the one that follows:

```
<body>
    <div
    style="width: 830px; height: 300px; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
        <div wicket:id="rangeBar"
        style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 300px; margin-right: 30px;"
        id="rangeBar1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I was expecting to retrieve data similar to the one I see in the browser web console like:

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 830px; height: 300px; margin: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
        <div wicket:id="rangeBar" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 300px; margin-right: 30px;" id="rangeBar1" class="shield-chart">
            <div id="shielddw" class="shield-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 400px; height: 300px; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; font-family: &amp; amp; #39; Segoe UI&amp;amp; #39; , Tahoma , Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="300">
                    <defs>
                    <clippath id="shielddx">
                    <rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="9999" height="300" stroke-width="0.000001"></rect></clippath>
                    <clippath id="shielddy">
                    <rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="331" height="210"></rect></clippath>
                    <filter id="a5a87bf2-0ea3-4664-8ceb-bd50b883a117" height="120%">
                    <fegaussianblur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"></fegaussianblur>
                    <fecomponenttransfer>
                    <fefunca type="linear" slope="0.2"></fefunca></fecomponenttransfer>
                    <femerge>
                    <femergenode></femergenode>
                    <femergenode in="SourceGraphic"></femergenode></femerge></filter></defs>
                    <rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#2D2D2D" x="0" y="0" width="400"
                    height="300" stroke-width="0.000001"></rect>  
                      ..... 
                 </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="shield-tooltip" style="pointer-events: none"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is there any way for getting such content in java?

Thanks,
Laura

UPDATE: Here is my java code

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = builder.build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(TEST_WEB_PAGE);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
OutputStream htmlStream = null;
File htmlFile = new File(ROOT + "etc/html/demo_apache_" + new Date() + ".html");
try {
    htmlStream = new FileOutputStream(htmlFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = content.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        htmlStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} finally {
    if (htmlStream != null)
        htmlStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the Java-code you are using to retrieve the data.

Comment: Question updated with Java code

Answer (score 3):

Is there any JavaScript included in the head tag that might be populating the div after the page has loaded?

If you obtain the page programmatically with Java, this JavaScript will not be executed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your project's set up, but perhaps you could render the page inside a web control programmatically and then pull the source back out of it

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: It depends whether you're using Android/Swing/ something else.

See if you can find a relevant control and take a look at the documentation

Comment: I'm writing a java back-end application. I have to save the content of a web page in pdf.

Comment: Can you not include a front-end library in the project? You wouldn't need to actually display it.

Comment: I think your best option is something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/33693350/497381