# Log into secured website, automatically print page as pdf

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, salesforce, pdfkit

I have been exploring ways to use python to log into a secure website (eg. Salesforce), navigate to a certain page and print (save) the page as pdf at a prescribed location.

I have tried using:

1. pdfkit.from_url: Use Request to get a session cookie, parse it then pass it as cookie into the wkhtmltopdf's options settings. This method does not work due to pdfkit not being able to recognise the cookie I passed.
2. pdfkit.from_file: Use Request.get to get the html of the page I want to print, then use pdfkit to convert the html file to pdf. This works but the page format and images are all missing.
3. Selenium: Use a webdriver to log in then navigate to the wanted page, call the windows.print function. This does not work because I can't pass any arguments to the window's SaveAs dialog.

Does anyone have any idea to get around?

Comment: One option could be to [save a screenshot using selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692179/export-as-pdf-using-selenium-webdriver-screenshot) (and convert to PDF).

Comment: The problem is full page screenshot is not available and there is no text rendering.

Answer (score 0):

- log in using requests
- use requests session mechanism to keep track of the cookie
- use session to retrieve the HTML page
- parse the HTML (use beautifulsoup)
- identify img tags and css links
- download locally the images and css documents
- rewrite the img src attributes to point to the locally downloaded images
- rewrite the css links to point to the locally downloaded css
- serialize the new HTML tree to a local .html file
- use whatever "HTML to PDF" solution to render the local .html file