# Using selenium drivers to Print to PDF

Tags: selenium, pdf, firefox, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am struggling with a problem.

I need to download PDF file when the Print dialog appears.

Here is an example of the dialog

[image]

I have tried both the chrome and firefox drivers. But unfortunately still cannot get it working.

I have found the following preference for the firefox

```
    fp.setPreference("print.print_to_file", true);
```

But it seems that it doesn't work.
It doesn't even get applied into the configuration variables set.

Please suggest any way to automate some actions with selenium and then save to PDF file when this print dialog appears.

Comment: This can't be done with Selenium. I can suggest to scrape the page, parse it, and write it to pdf by yourself

Comment: See this Question hope you will get answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692179/export-as-pdf-using-selenium-webdriver-screenshot

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64533554/1776132) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to know selenium is a web automation tool. so it can only operate things belongs to browser. Even that, it can't operate all things belongs to browser, like address bar, favior bar, menu bar of browser.

For most case, the print dialog is not belongs to browser, it supplyed by OS or other software installed on OS. so selenium can't operate it is reasonable.

If your script code by java, you can use java.awt.robot to capture the dialog
and click 'print to file'.

If java.awt.robot can worked as your expect, I think you aslo need to set browser options in your script to give a path for browser to save the printed file, just like when you download file, browse will ask you where to save.

if you not to set that options, i guess it will pop-up another dialog to ask you where to save and this dialog is also not belongs to browser.
it's not easy to use java.awt.robot to set the save path.

Because you need to consider the possbility of script run on different OS,  use abosulte path is not workable on different OS. Besides if your script run with seleniu grid, it will make you craze. So if testing print to file feature is not important, i recommend you test it manuall.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Print to PDF using Testmate as below
http://thetestmate.com/save-as-pdf-in-chrome-testmate-selenium/