# ChromeDriver --print-to-pdf after page load

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), Chrome can be started in headless mode with `--print-to-pdf` in order to export a PDF of a web page. This works well for pages accessible with a `GET` request.

Trying to find a print-to-pdf solution that would allow me to export a PDF after executing multiple navigation request from within Chrome. Example: open `google.com`, input a search query, click the first result link, export to PDF.

Looking at the [very limited amount of available] docs and samples, I failed to find a way to instruct Chrome to export a PDF, after a page loads. I'm using the Java `chrome-driver`.

One possible solution not involving Chrome, is by using a tool like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org). Going on this path would force me to - before sending the HTML to the tool - do the following:

- save the HTML in a local file
- traverse the DOM, and download all file links (images, js, css, etc)

Don't prefer this path as it would require a lot of tinkering [I assume] on my part to get downloads' file paths correct for `wkhtmltopdf` to read correctly.

Is there a way to instruct Chrome to print to PDF, but only after a page loads?

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: Nothing to share as I got nowhere with my attempts. But can explain my process. It involved basically trying any [Chrome preferences](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup) that made sense at that time to me, in order to force Chrome to print to PDF after `window.print()` is executed. Looked also at the [command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but those were of no help to me also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are no answers, I will explain my workaround. Instead of trying to find how to request from Chrome to print the current page, I went down another route.

For this example we will try to download the results page from Google on the query 'example':

1. Navigate with `driver.get("google.com")`, input the query 'example', click 'Google Search'
2. Wait for the results page to load
3. Retrieve the page source with `driver.getPageSource()`
4. Parse source with e.g. Jsoup in order to remap all relative links to point to an endpoint defined for this purpose (explained below) - example to `localhost:8080`. Link './style.css' would become 'localhost:8080/style.css'
5. Save HTML to a file, e.g. named 'query-example'
6. Run `chrome --print-to-pdf localhost:8080/search?id=query-example`

What will happen is that chrome will request the HTML from our controller, and for resources defined in the HTML we return, it will go to our controller - since we remapped relative links - which will in turn forward that request to the real location of the resource - google.com. Below is an example Spring controller, and note that the example is incomplete and is here only as a guidance.

```cs
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class InternationalOffloadRestController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search/html")
  public String getHtml(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
    File file = new File("location of the HTML file", id);
    try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file)) {
      return IOUtils.toString(input, HTML_ENCODING);
    }
  }
  @RequestMapping("/**") // forward all remapped links to google.com
  public void forward(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, ...) {
    URI uri = new URI("https", null, "google.com", -1, 
      request.getRequestURI(), request.getQueryString(), null);
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", uri.toString());
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any update on this? It seems odd that this isn't an available command on every navigation.

Comment: I've done it with a shell script... download the page_source, grep out the links to css and images, download those to directory, sed to point links to the local files, then wkhtmltopdf

Comment: @J.Win. please consider sharing your script, someone visiting might find it useful.

Comment: What if there's a dubious style.css that's like 20GB on the server? Haha you'd promptly be defeated.

Answer (score 9):

This is indeed possible to do through Selenium Chromedriver, by means of the `ExecuteChromeCommandWithResult` method. When executing the command `Page.printToPDF`, a base-64-encoded PDF document is returned in the "data" item of the result dictionary.

A C# example, which should be easy to translate into Java, is available in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58698226/2416627

Here is another C# example, which illustrates some useful options:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var driverOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    // In headless mode, PDF writing is enabled by default (tested with driver major version 85)
    driverOptions.AddArgument("headless");
    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverOptions))
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d => d.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#questions")).Count == 1);
        // Output a PDF of the first page in A4 size at 90% scale
        var printOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "paperWidth", 210 / 25.4 },
            { "paperHeight", 297 / 25.4 },
            { "scale", 0.9 },
            { "pageRanges", "1" }
        };
        var printOutput = driver.ExecuteChromeCommandWithResult("Page.printToPDF", printOptions) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        var pdf = Convert.FromBase64String(printOutput["data"] as string);
        File.WriteAllBytes("stackoverflow-page-1.pdf", pdf);
    }
}
```

The options available for the `Page.printToPDF` call are documented here:

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF

Answer (score 4):

Using [ChromiumDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/chromium/ChromiumDriver.java) from Java Selenium 4.x.x release, this can be achieved.

```
String command = "Page.printToPDF";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("landscape", false);
Map<String, Object> output = driver.executeCdpCommand(command, params);
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("export.pdf");
    byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode((String)output.get("data"));
    fileOutputStream.write(byteArray);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Source: [Selenium_CDP](https://github.com/sergueik/selenium_cdp/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/sergueik/selenium/ChromiumCdpTest.java#L706)

Answer (score 2):

An example for doing this from command line, takes a little tinkering with the page html and `sed`:

```
LOGIN='myuserid'
PASSW='mypasswd'
AUTH='pin=$LOGIN&accessCode=$PASSW&Submit=Submit'
TIMESTAMP=`TZ=HST date -d "today" +"%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p HST"`
wget -q --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies \
    --post-data $AUTH \
    https://csea.ehawaii.gov/iwa/index.html
sed -i 's#href="/iwa/css#href="./bin#g' index.html
sed -i 's#src="/iwa/images#src="./bin#g' index.html
wkhtmltopdf -q --print-media-type \
            --header-left "$d" --header-font-size 10 \
            --header-line --header-spacing 10 \
            --footer-left "Page [page] of [toPage]" --footer-font-size 10 \
            --footer-line --footer-spacing 10 \
            --footer-right "$TIMESTAMP" \
            --margin-bottom 20 --margin-left 15 \
            --margin-top 20 --margin-right 15 \
            index.html index.pdf
```

Assuming valid cookies, further pages available after login could be accessed like this:

```
wget -q --load-cookies cookies.txt https://csea.ehawaii.gov/otherpage.html
wkhtmltopdf <all the options> otherpage.html otherpage.pdf
```

Also, I had previously dumped all the css and images in a local `bin` directory, something like this:

```
wget -r -A.jpg -A.gif -A.css -nd -Pbin \
    https://csea.ehawaii.gov/iwa/index.html
```