# How to print to PDF using C# Selenium and headless Chrome?

Tags: c#, selenium, pdf, printing, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using C# Selenium with Chrome and printing using SendKey, but it's not very optimal as it needs an unlocked desktop to work and I can't use my development machine while the tests are running. Since --print-to-pdf works with headless, shouldn't it also work with Selenium?

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970792/1275774