# Scale down <canvas> within grid container so, that <canvas> retains its aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid, object-fit

I have a problem scaling down `canvas` elements that belong to `grid` container.

```css
html * {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: Arial;
}

#wrapper {
 border: 1px solid green;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 32vmin);
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(32vmin, 43vmin);
 grid-column-gap: 0.4em;
 grid-row-gap: 0.4em;
 align-items: center;
 justify-items: center;
}

#wrapper > * {
 object-fit: contain;
 max-height: 32vmin;
 max-width: 32vmin;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

#canvas0 {
 width:20vmin;
 height:60vmin;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas0"></canvas>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code shows `canvas` that have `width: 20` and `height: 60` scaled with the result aspect ratio of `1:2`. What I need is a `canvas` element that fits into maximum `grid` row height and column width, and, remains constant with its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution that uses `Javascript`. As I see it now, `canvas` elements must have their own `width` and `height` attributes that differ from `CSS` attributes. Canvas `width` and `height` is the dimensions used for drawing on the canvas. `CSS` `width` and `height` represent elements layout.

`CSS` plus `HTML` layout stays basically the same from original question. Few changes here and there, but the same in general. Following that, I am setting `width` and `height` to every `canvas` element in `Javascript`, taking dimensions and aspect ratio from server. Then I scale `canvas` elements according to aspect ratio.

This SO answer, and the question, have helped me to solve scaling problem.

[How do I scale one rectangle to the maximum size possible within another rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373879/8339821)